# TFS/VSTS - Child tasks under features appearing as un-parented on board

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have created a task in an iteration, and it has child tasks. On both the feature and the task I can see the parent/child link.

However, on the project board they appear as "unparented" for no obvious reason.

As you can see, the links definitely exist:

[image]

[image]

And then in the board/iteration list the tasks don't have a parent:
[image]

[image]

What do I need to do to make them no longer unparented?

Comment: I just got a notification someone upvoted this. You have my condolences if you're still stuck on either this issue or using TFS/Azure DevOps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hierarchy of work items is this:

- Epic

  - Feature

    - Product Backlog Item / User Story

      - Task

The task is showing as unparented because it's not the child of a product backlog item. A PBI is intended to be a unit of work that can be accomplished within a single sprint/iteration. A Feature tracks multiple PBIs, potentially across sprints.

Comment: Thanks! What would count as an epic? Could I just create one epic for the whole of my project with many features, or is there a better approach?

Comment: An epic is for a major initiative -- an epic might be "redesign web site", with features for things like "implement two-factor authentication" and then PBIs for the individual requirements of the implementation of two-factor authentication. It's also worth noting that you don't need to use Epics or Features.

Comment: I see. Interesting, thanks. You mentioned not using epics or features. Do you mean I could use just PBI's and tasks, and they would still work on the boards correctly?

Comment: Absolutely. You can even turn off Epics and Features in the board settings -- there's a "Backlog Levels" area.